# qt creator using old version of protoc

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use protocol buffers in my Qt app, but I keep getting this message after I've linked the library to my project.

error message

[image]

"Unrecognized syntax identifier "proto3". This parser only recognizes "proto2".

My protoc --version gives me version 3.0.0, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Post the actual error message.  Links can go stale making the question incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Had more than one protobuf compiler on my system and Qt was using the older one instead of the newer one. Fixed by removing it.